# Will the JNA Kernel32 mapping work on a 32-bit machine?

Tags: java, windows, 32bit-64bit, jna

My application includes the following call to JNA's pre-cooked [`Kernel32` interface](https://twall.github.io/jna/3.3.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32.html):

```
int processID = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcessId();
```

Can I build my application into a JAR using my 64-bit laptop and expect this to work on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: Note: I don't have access to a 32-bit machine, hence I can't test this. I'm assuming the answer is "yes", but would like validation from experts in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly Java compiles to platform-independent byte code, so my question boils down to two sub-questions:

1. Is the library binding done at compile time or runtime?
2. Is the `Kernel32` interface correctly written to describe both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the `kernel32.dll` file.

Question 1 was obvious, given some thought. JNA is not distributed with a compiler, so the binding must be done at runtime. This is confirmed by a statement on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/twall/jna):

> JNA uses a small JNI library stub to dynamically invoke native code.

Question 2 is harder to answer, but given that all the types in use appear to be architecture-neutral (`int` is safe on Windows according to [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#how-do-i-map-a-native-long-type), all pointers use the [`WinNT.HANDLE`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinNT.HANDLE.html), etc.) then I'm pretty confident it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the 32-bit libraries and all you do is write Java code to call it and do other Java things, then yes, it will work on 32-bit machines too.

Java code compiles to architecture independent byte code, there is no such thing as 32 bit or 64 bit byte code.

There could only be problem if you would include the 64-bit libraries as those would not run on 32-bit machines obviously.

Comment: I'm quite happy with the idea that Java code is architecture independent. I guess my question boils down to how JNA works - if it dynamically searches for the relevant API at runtime or whether something occurs during compile time. I guess it must be dynamic.

Comment: Yes, it does. From the main GitHub page: "*JNA uses a small JNI library stub to dynamically invoke native code.*". I suppose that answers it.

Comment: You should add it as an aswer.. :)